# Cordova app crashes in iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, ios9

I have a Cordova app which works on iOS 8, but when I try to run it in the iOS 9 simulator it crashes inside some web view code, seems to be something concerning CSS or an SVG. Does anybody have an idea how to debug this?

I posted the stack trace as an image since I didn't find any way to copy it as text. Sorry about that.

Stack trace of the crash:

[image: ios 9 crash stack trace]

Comment: I would debug that first. Just to post a stacktrace... i think that is a bit complicated. Comment out all images inside your application (which should be no problem with a text editor programm) and run the app. Add image by image and you'll find the image which crashed your application.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and it's the svg images... I have a "loading" svg image when the app goes to the server. When I removed it the app didn't crash at that point, but it crashed on the next svg image it loaded. My app has many svg images, is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: found it. It was my app's splash screen, a 1.2 Mb svg file. Everything worked after I converted it to png.